# Windows storage spaces will not let me remove a retired drive, now the pool is offline

Tags: hard-drive, powershell, raid, storage-spaces, storage-pool

I'm going a bit insane trying to fix this issue with my file server it's a plex server with some files built on windows 10 using parity. I had 6 drives and 1 failed, storage spaces would not let me remove the drive, I would get a lack of resiliency error, so I added another drive... Same error... so I added another... Now I'm broke and still can't access my data. I physically removed the dead drive as it seemed to be causing windows to take 30+ mins to boot.
https://ibb.co/mh8Cfxx

https://ibb.co/G97bJpN
When I try to remove or repair the pool in powershell nothing happens (see pics) it just says job suspended...
I don't know what to do, but really need a few of the files back, my wife stored her school stuff on there.
Thank you (sorry if I formated this poorly, my first time on superuser)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Big fugly picture]

Plugging the dead drive back in and restarting the system 3 or 4 times randomly allowed me to remove the drive (I think because the drive only randomly died).
I still don't understand what happened, but glad it's back to life.

Will start migrating to Linux.

Comment: While I like Windows as a server in many ways, migrating to Linux is clearly a good idea for anything resembling a storage server unless you are using hardware RAID. Storage spaces is utterly broken in so many ways, and the long-standing breaking issues (years!) indicate Microsoft has no intention of making a working product.